# Data send with Handlebarsjs disappearing after post

Tags: node.js, express, post, routes, handlebars.js

First time using `express-handlebars`.
I used this for the page title

```
router.get('/register', function(req, res) {
    req.session.title = "Register";
    res.render('register', {
        active: { nav_active_register: true },
        title: req.session.title
    });
});
```

I use this to append the word "Register" after my websites title in the following format:

`MyWebsite | Regster`

I then use: `router.post('/register', function(req, res) {` I then find, validate and store the relevant information in mongodb and send a flash msg alerting the user of any errors, if any.

When bad data is validated and error messages have been sent (eg, improper email format), the title disappears and is no longer displayed as it was moments ago.
I then get

`MyWebsite |`

If I refresh the page, it is still not there but if I leave and return the page, the correct title reappears.

I have searched the internet for a solution and have tried sending the data alternative ways but none work.

How do I get the word "Register" to stay in the title after `post`?

(Or atleast why is it doing this)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure that you are setting the title: parameter in your

`router.post('/register', function(req, res){....`

method as you are in your `router.get('/register'...` method.

Comment: _http_outgoing.js:356                                                                            
    throw new Error('Can\'t set headers after they are sent.');

Comment: I now get this error also css does not appear to have worked and the app stops running @Jim Factor